# Generic Parsing with default value

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to create a generic parsing method but I am stuck.
I want to be able to take in two types, an object of type1, and a default value of type2.
Then I want to try and parse the type1 object to the type2 object, if that doesn't work then return the default value.

Obviously the code below is invalid and doesn't work. But this is what I am going for.
Does anyone know how to accomplish this in C#?

```
public static K TryGenericParse<T, K>(T objectToParse, K defaultValue)
{
    K returnValue;

    if (!K.TryParse(objectToParse, out returnValue))
        returnValue = defaultValue;

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done using generics. The TryParse functions on Int32, DateTime etc are completely different functions that just happen to have the same name. Maybe you can do something with Reflection.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels Yea I know try parse wouldn't would on a generic. I was just curious to see if anyone has implemented something like this. It would make my life easier if it existed.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't see an actual answer to this question. Plus this "consensus" is biased since it targets those who actually use Meta, and not a simple random sample of the population as a whole.

Comment: Sorry, which question are you referring to? Also, the consensus is clearly the consensus of those who care enough about the site to discuss the issue. The fact that not everybody participates in a consensus doesn't make it less of a consensus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TypeConverter for this purpose. You can retrieve type convert using static method of TypeDescriptor, GetConverter.

```
public static TOuput TryGenericParse<TInput, TOuput>(TInput input)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TOuput));
    if (!converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof (TInput)))
        return default(TOuput);
    return (TOuput)converter.ConvertFrom(input);
}

bool bl = TryGenericParse<string, bool>("True");
double dbl = TryGenericParse<string, double>("3.222");
```